# Using Ito Isometry formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

How would I use the Ito Isometry formula to compute,

$$E\left [ \left ( \int_{0}^{t}g(s,W_s)dW_s \right )^2 \right ]$$

for the case $g(t,W_t)=(1+t^2+W_t)$ with $W_t$ being Brownian motion.

I would really appreciate any help on this. Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Just apply Itô isometry, and the result almost follow...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write a solution, also as an exercise for me...

**Step 1: apply Ito isometry**

$I=E[\left(\int_0^t g(s,W_s) dW_s\right)^2]=E[(\int_0^t g(s,W_s)^2 ds]$

**Step 2: Insert and expand**

$I=E[\int_0^t (1+s^4+W_s^2 +2s^2+2sW_s+2W_s )ds]$

**Step 3: Exchange expectation with integral**

This way we can prove that:

$E[\int_0^t W_s ds]=\int_0^t E[W_t]ds=0$

$E[\int_0^t sW_s ds]=\int_0^t sE[W_t]ds=0$

$E[\int_0^t W^2_s ds]=\int_0^t E[W^2_s] ds=\int_0^t s ds=t^2/2$

The rest is just deterministic integrals:

$I=t+t^5/5+t^2/2+2t^3/3$

Comment: I'm unsure how to you step 2 and the deterministic integrals in step 3. Would you be able to explain this in more detail?